# Why does a certain Protocol work without a class that implements it?

Tags: objective-c, protocols, uikeyinput

I have worked quite a lot with protocols like delegates and data sources and I recently worked on something using the `UIKeyInput` protocol.
I am used to things like `self.tableView.delegate = self` but with `UIKeyInput` I didn't need to that. But the protocol methods I implemented (e.g. `insertText:` etc.) got called nevertheless.

Can someone explain to me how this works?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: On what class did you implement `UIKeyInput` ?

Comment: Custom subclass of `UIView`

Comment: It got a handle to your self somehow.  Maybe in starboard/zib?

Comment: None of that involved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cocoa Touch framework has a concept of the "responder chain", which is how it figures out where to deliver UI input events.  The "first responder" is at the head of the responder chain.  When iOS has a keyboard input event, it checks if the current first responder supports the UIKeyInput protocol and calls those methods if it does.

You don't need to register as the UIKeyInputDelegate for another object, because the framework defines the recipient for those messages as the first responder.